# What's the most efficient way to split a tuple in two?

Tags: python, tuples

In Python 3 I have a tuple:

```
a = ('aa', 'bb', 'cc', '|', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff')
```

I want to split the tuple into two tuples. The tuples must be divided at the `|`. The index of `|` is not static.
Expected result:

```
a = ('aa', 'bb', 'cc',)
b = ('dd', 'ee', 'ff',)
```

What's the most efficient way to split a tuple in two using a divider?

I know tuples are immutable, but circumstances require me to be a little pragmatic.

**Edit:**
In my case, there will be 0 or 1 separator (`|`).
The data in the tuple will have a length of more than 1.

Comment: What have you tried? What if the separator occurs multiple times? Or not at all?

Comment: Also tuples aren't so much "meant to be" immutable, as... actually immutable.

Comment: Hint: [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

Comment: Not that the immutable quality really changes what to do here - you just can't modify it in place (which would seem like a terrible idea anyway, even if you were using a mutable collection).

Comment: Why not just try doing this task with a simple for loop? I understand that it would require some more code, but surely it would be just as efficient as the other concise methods. It's just strange the OP is asking for more advanced methods, but hasn't shown the most straightforward approach possible.

Comment: @RoadRunner Because I want my code to be efficient and clean.

Comment: @Vingtoft A single for loop is not efficient?

Comment: @RoadRunner for-loop search function would have a worst case runtime of N. Thats not fast.
I did not know if a build-in python function existed. Many of pythons build-in functions are implemented in C and runs much faster than pure python.

Comment: @Vingtoft A worst case of `O(N)` is great, don't understand why you think this is bad. As @tobias_k pointed out below, even using `groupby` would have the same complexity. Same with the slicing list answer.

Comment: @RoadRunner and I don't understand way you think its a bad idea to seek knowledge in order to become a better developer. O(n) is not fast. Thats why so much effort has been put into creating faster search algorithms, such as divide and conquer. Thank you for your interest in my question. Have a nice day!

Comment: @Vingtoft What do you mean, "O(n) is not fast"? It's obviously the best possible.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I did not know it was the best possible. Also, "best possible" does not equal fast. I also believe (correct me if Im wrong) that utilizing built-in functions are faster (implemented in pure C), compared to writing custom python. I did not know if a built-in function used a multi-process divide and conquer implementation. This would still have a O(n) but would run a lot faster.
I'm not sure I agree with RoadRunner's principle that its "strange to ask for more advanced solutions". I believe you should always try to improve :-)

Comment: @Vingtoft I think you misunderstood me, I said *"It's just strange the OP is asking for more advanced methods, **but hasn't shown the most straightforward approach possible**"*. I also did not say that asking for more advanced solutions is bad, just wondering why you didn't post your attempted solution to begin with. This shows that you've put effort into the problem beforehand, instead of just asking people to write code for you. This would also be helpful for users answering to compare the efficiency between the **your** approach and a **library function** approach.

Comment: @RoadRunner You are obviously right since the question got so many down votes. I will improve my questions in the future. Thanks!

Comment: @Vingtoft Btw I did not down vote this question, I was just trying to make suggestions for you. Usually questions will get downvoted if their is no attempt shown by the OP. You probably did this in the background, but if others don't see it, then they will just downvote. I hope I did not come across as rude.  Good luck :-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested in comments, you could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to subdivide the tuple into "not a separator" and "separator" groups and then pick those groups that are not separators. This works for arbitrary numbers of segments, but can also be unpacked into two variables if you know to have exactly two groups.

```
>>> a = ('a', 'b', 'c', '|', 'd', 'e', 'f', '|', 'g', 'h', 'i')
>>> [tuple(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(a, key='|'.__eq__) if not k]
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f'), ('g', 'h', 'i')]
```

This could also be generalized to allow for *different* separators, using e.g. `groupby(a, key='|-'.__contains__)`.

---

Regarding comments: The time complexity of this should be O(n), just as when using `index`, which also is the best you can expect if you don't know where to split and the tuple is not ordered in any way. Note, however, that `groupby` presents some overhead which makes this solution about 4-5 times *slower* than using <strike>`index`</strike> tuple slicing. It's still more versatile and easier applicable for unknown numbers of groups, though.

Comment: The best part about this is, it works for 0, 1, or a million separators.

Comment: Do you really think that's "the most efficient way"?

Comment: @StefanPochmann I did not time it, but I don't see a real problem with that. It may be slower than calling `index`, as this will always scan the _entire_ list for more occurrences of the separator. If you have a better idea, please suggest.

Comment: @tobias_k Nice answer, Do you know what the time complexity of this is?

Comment: @RoadRunner Time complexity should be O(n), same as using `index`, but seemingly with some overhead.

Comment: I don't have a new idea, I think `index`+slicing is it.

Comment: When you say O(n) is "the best you can expect if you don't know where to split and the tuple is not ordered in any way", do you mean you could beat O(n) if you did know the location or it were ordered? Are you thinking about creating slice "views" then instead of normal tuples?

Comment: @StefanPochmann No, I did not even think about the costs for actually _creating_ the sub-tuples but only for finding the separator. But of course this only solidifies that it can't be faster than O(n).

Comment: Ah, darn. I benchmarked this further and only now realize the question is closed so I can't post it. I tried with `a = ('a',) * 10**8 + ('|',)`, so your scanning the entire list is not a disadvantage because `index` must do that, too. Yours takes about 5.7 seconds for pure scanning, and 7.4 seconds for scanning to tuple (so creating the tuple is 1.7 seconds overhead). Calling `index` takes 1.5 seconds and slicing takes 0.46 seconds.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Yes, it seems the real culprit is not `groupby` but the `tuple` creation as opposed to slicing: `tuple(itertools.islice(a, 1000, 9000))` takes about 3 times longer than `a[1000:9000]` (with `a = tuple(range(10000))`). Probably tuple slicing is implemented very efficiently in C; possibly it does not even copy anyting but just creates a view, as the tuple in immutable anyway.

Comment: Well, *both* are a culprit, and `groupby`'s scanning is the much larger part. Creating the tuple is a relatively small overhead. Here's my test now, btw (just with 10^7 instead of 10^8 because of ideone's time limit): https://ideone.com/g0JG4G

Comment: And nah, slicing doesn't just create a view. That wouldn't take 0.46 seconds. I think it's also not something that Python would do, at least not CPython. It does have downsides. Java previously did that with strings when creating substrings, btw, but gave up on it and now copies.

Answer (score 6):

You can find the '|' using `index`, and you can slice the tuple using slices.

```
a = ('a', 'b', 'c', '|', 'd', 'e', 'f')
i = a.index('|')
a,b = a[:i],a[i+1:]
```

Comment: Can you generalise this for multiple separators? Or not at all? This will fail for the latter case.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ The OP specifically wants to split a tuple "in two"

Comment: Maybe... but this won't solve anything besides OP's problem. If you're fine with that, then so be it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ code can be repeated while separatot is present in b string. Does it a problem?

Comment: @splash58 yes, it is a problem.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ i don't see any problem - https://eval.in/921204

Comment: @splash58 The problem isn't that it doesn't work, it's that it's tedious to implement.

Comment: @splash58 It also doesn't generalise to multiple disparate separators as easily. See the other answer.